# dynamic array build in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Input:

Comp1|  Comp2   
 Item A |   HD A
Item A  |   HD B
Item A  |   HD C
HD A    |   HD AA
HD A        | HD AB
HD AA   |   HD AAAA
HD AA   |   HD AAAB
HD AB   |   HD ABAB

Desired Output:

Item A | HD A | HD AA | HD AAAA
Item A | HD A | HD AA | HD AAAB
Item A | HD A | HD AB | HD AAAB

desired outcome is to create an array dynamically in JS so that the input structure can be further flattened and all the occurances (dependencies) of the any element are collected in single row.

Comment: can you show us your efforts before?

Comment: How is `Item A | HD A | HD AB | HD AAAB` derived? Shouldn't that be `Item A | HD A | HD AB | HD ABAB`?

Comment: @brebraw: sorry, you are right...

Comment: I have tried with one approach marked below: however it does not give me full output, it rather gives me only first row as correct output

Comment: Arr = []; <br>
obj = {};<br>

//fill array<br>
for(i=0;i<data.length-1;i++) {<br>
comp = data[i].component;<br>
name = data[i].name;<br>
flag = 1;<br>
obj["component"] = comp;<br>
obj["name"] = name;<br>

//fill objects<br>
for(j=i+1;j<data.length-i;j++){<br>
if(name == data[j].component){<br>
var str = "level"+flag;<br>
flag = flag+1;<br>
obj[str] = data[j].name;<br>
comp = data[j].component;<br>
name = data[j].name;<br>
data.splice(j,1);<br>
j=i+1;<br>
} } <br>
Arr.push(obj);<br>

obj = {};<br>
}<br>
console.log(Arr);<br>

}<br>

Comment: @lateralus: mentioned my piece of code, does not look formatted although I entered <br> after every line to make look formatted